# Phone Calling Via Internet using APIs in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, webrtc

I need to make a calling App in Flutter, there is a backend developer aligned with me. We need to make calling app just like whatsapp calling. but we can not use any SDK or other paid services. Backend Developer said he will provide me Socket api and webrtc, can anyone guide. how can I integrate WEB RTC and socket APIs in Flutter

Answer (score 1):

You can use [flutter_webrtc](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webrtc) plugin.

For the websocket communication, use [web_socket_client](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_client) or [web_socket_channel](https://pub.dev/packages/web_socket_channel).

None of these are paid and are available with some good articles, example:
https://www.videosdk.live/blog/flutter-webrtc